# UITableView is not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My UITableView is not scrolling in my today extension.

TodayViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TodayViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

TodayViewController.m

```
#import "TodayViewController.h"
#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>

@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding>
{
    int expandAmount;
}

@end

@implementation TodayViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.preferredContentSize.width, 3 * 44.0);
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
//[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyResuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSMutableArray *movieTitles = [self getSportsTitlesFromPList];


    cell.textLabel.text = [movieTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = channelNumber;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"test";
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [_channels removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    return cell;
}
```

I know it is not recommended by Apple to scroll in the today extension. But I would just like to know why I cant scroll my `UITableView`. I thought it might have been because the view was sitting on top of the `UITableView`, but then I brought the `UITableView` to the front, so that it could receive any touches.

Comment: Why are you adding a second table view to the existing table view in the table view controller?

Comment: You have two tables! The one you just added and the one you inherited from. Both are using self as the delegate by default. Why are you adding a table to what is already a table?

Comment: ahh @RoryMcKinnel and rmaddy thank you. I was no aware that I was inheriting self.tableView. However, am now just using self.tableView, the one I inherited. but still no scroll.

Comment: @Mr.T https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html

Comment: From the docs: "Note
Avoid putting a scroll view inside a Today widget. It’s difficult for users to scroll within a widget without inadvertently scrolling the Today view." However this would imply it should work, just somewhat tricky to use 8^).

Comment: Can you update your code to your new code in the question.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel updated.

Comment: You are recreating self.tableView when it is already created for you by the super class? All you should need to do is provide the delegate methods.

Comment: hmmm. If i remove self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init...] i still have no scroll ability.

Comment: @Changerrs Take out everything in `viewDidLoad` except the call to `[super viewDidLoad]` and see what happens.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel nothing happens... no blank rows, nothing.